# error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/boot.mod' not found

Tags: grub2

My linux(ubuntu 14.04) unexpectedly stopped working after reboot. I caught:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/boot.mod' not found. 
Entering rescue mode ...
```

How to solve this? And what could be a reason for such problem? Ubuntu was loading updates when I initiated reboot.

Comment: You told the system to reboot **while** it was installing updates? Do you have a linux USB stick or DVD lying around?

Comment: Should I reinstall it now?

Comment: Do you have a Linux USB or DVD or not? If yes, you should be able to fix it from there.

Comment: Yes, sure I do have